# Correct SQL statement for 3 tables query

Tags: mysql, sql

Please be assured that I searched a lot on SE for an answer similar to mine but didn't get any good result and here I am asking for some help.

I have 3 tables as follows:

```
Table Professors:
+---------+--------+
| idProf  |  name  |
+---------+--------+
|    1    | Ben    |
|    2    | John   |
|    3    | Bob    |
+---------+--------+

Table Classes:
+---------+--------+------------+
| idClass |  name  | profRefId  | 
+---------+--------+------------+
|    1    | French |    1       |
|    2    | English|    1       |
|    3    | German |    3       |
|    4    | Science|    2       |
+---------+--------+------------+

Table Lessons:
+----------+----------+--------------+
| idLesson |   name   |  classRefId  | 
+----------+----------+--------------+
|    1     | Lesson1  |      1       |
|    2     | Lesson2  |      1       |
|    3     | Lesson3  |      2       |
|    4     | Lesson4  |      4       |
|    5     | Lesson5  |      4       |
|    6     | Lesson6  |      3       |
+----------+----------+--------------+
```

Now, what I was struggling to achieve is:

I pass idProf as a URL parameter (`$_GET['idProf']`)

And I would like the right SQL statement based on that param to list all the classes for that professor and inside each class list its lessons.

Something that will look like this on a webpage:

[image: structure of the web page]

Comment: You need a combination of the right *query* with the right application code to *render* the data returned from the query. Narrow this question to just the query aspect by showing expected query results from the data given, and delete the renderings shown.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT a.name ProfessorName, b.name ClassName, c.name LessonName
FROM Professors a
INNER JOIN Classes b
ON a.idProf=b.profRefID
INNER JOIN Lessons c
ON b.idClass=c.classRefID
```

Comment: @MohamedAnisDahmani -- What didn't work.  You only tagged it with SQL, but is it SQL Server?

Comment: I am working with PHP and mySQL and passing the ID of the professor in a URL var. Does this help?

Comment: What part didn't work?  Did you get an error message?  If so, what was it?

Comment: the statement is fine but the result is not what I am looking for

Comment: Maybe you should be more clear, then, about what you're looking for.